# Kafka Avro To BigQuery using Apache Beam in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-beam, avro

Here is the scenario:

Kafka  To BigQuery using Apache Beam. This is an alternative to BigQuerySinkConnector [WePay] using Kafka Connect.

I have been able to read Avro message from Kafka Topic. I am also able to print the contents to console accurately. I am looking for help with writing these KafkaRecords to BigQuery table.

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        //Customer is an auto generated class from avro schema using eclipse avro maven plugin
        // Read from Kafka Topic and get KafkaRecords
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<KafkaRecord<String, Customer>>> input = KafkaIO.<String, Customer>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers("http://server1:9092")
                       .withTopic("test-avro")
                       .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("specific.avro.reader", (Object)"true"))
                       .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("auto.offset.reset", (Object)"earliest"))
                       .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("schema.registry.url", (Object)"http://server2:8181"))
                       .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                       .withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class)KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(Customer.class));
        
        
        // Print kafka records to console log
        
        pipeline.apply(input)
                .apply("ExtractRecord", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KafkaRecord<String,Customer>, KafkaRecord<String,Customer>>() { 
                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        KafkaRecord<String, Customer> record = (KafkaRecord<String, Customer>) c.element();
                        KV<String, Customer> log = record.getKV();
                        System.out.println("Key Obtained: " + log.getKey());
                        System.out.println("Value Obtained: " + log.getValue().toString());
                        c.output(record);
                        
                    }
                }));
                
        // Write each record to BigQuery Table 
        // Table is already available in BigQuery so create disposition would be CREATE_NEVER
        // Records to be appended to table - so write disposition would be WRITE_APPEND
        // All fields in the Customer object have corresponding column names and datatypes - so it is one to one mapping
        
        // Connection to BigQuery is through service account JSON file. This file has been set as environment variable in run config of eclipse project
        // Set table specification for BigQuery
          String bqTable = "my-project:my-dataset:my-table";
```

The current examples available - shows how to manually set a schema and assign field by field the values. I am looking for an automated way to infer the Customer Avro object and assign it to the columns directly without such manual field by field assignment.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I was able to make the following work.

I would welcome review comments to share concerns / propose better solutions.

```
        SchemaRegistryClient registryClient = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(http://server2:8181,10);
        SchemaMetadata latestSchemaMetadata;
        Schema avroSchema = null; 
        try {
            // getLatestSchemaMetadata takes the subject name which is topic-value format where "-value" is suffixed to topic
            // so if topic is "test-avro" then subject is "test-avro-value"
            latestSchemaMetadata = registryClient.getLatestSchemaMetadata("test-avro-value");
            avroSchema = new Schema.Parser().parse(latestSchemaMetadata.getSchema());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IO Exception while obtaining registry data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Client Exception while obtaining registry data");
            e.printStackTrace();
            
        }
        
        // Printing avro schema obtained
        System.out.println("---------------- Avro schema ----------- " + avroSchema.toString());
        
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        
        
        // Read from Kafka Topic and get KafkaRecords
        // Create KafkaIO.Read with Avro schema deserializer
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        KafkaIO.Read<String, GenericRecord> read = KafkaIO.<String, GenericRecord>read()
            .withBootstrapServers("http://server1:9092")
            .withTopic(KafkaConfig.getInputTopic())
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("schema.registry.url", "http://server2:8181"))
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("specific.avro.reader", (Object)"true"))
            .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("auto.offset.reset", (Object)"earliest"))
            .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
            .withValueDeserializerAndCoder((Class) KafkaAvroDeserializer.class, AvroCoder.of(avroSchema));
        
        
        // Set Beam Schema
        
        org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(avroSchema); 
        
        // Print kafka records to console log
                        
        // Write each record to BigQuery Table 
        // Table is already available in BigQuery so create disposition would be CREATE_NEVER
        // Records to be appended to table - so write disposition would be WRITE_APPEND
        // All fields in the Customer object have corresponding column names and datatypes - so it is one to one mapping
        
        // Connection to BigQuery is through service account JSON file. This file has been set as environment variable in run config of eclipse project
        // Set table specification for BigQuery
          String bqTable = "my-project:my-dataset:my-table";
        
        p.apply(read)
        .apply("ExtractRecord", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KafkaRecord<String,GenericRecord>, KV<String, GenericRecord>>() { 
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                KafkaRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = (KafkaRecord<String, GenericRecord>) c.element();
                KV<String, GenericRecord> log = record.getKV();
                System.out.println("Key Obtained: " + log.getKey());
                System.out.println("Value Obtained: " + log.getValue().toString());
                c.output(log);
                
            }
        }))
        .apply(Values.<GenericRecord>create()).setSchema(beamSchema, TypeDescriptor.of(GenericRecord.class) ,AvroUtils.getToRowFunction(GenericRecord.class, avroSchema), AvroUtils.getFromRowFunction(GenericRecord.class))
        .apply(BigQueryIO.<GenericRecord>write()
                .to(tableSpec)
                .useBeamSchema()
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
        
        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

The above works with CREATE_IF_NEEDED also.